# How to extract the URL from the string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, url

How to extract the URL from the below string. I searched in web for regex but it extracts only if http:// or www. How to extract for both the type of inputs?

**Regex**:
http://blog.houen.net/java-get-url-from-string/

**Case1**:

```
bhjhrwww.rrjhttp://www.google.com
```

Result:

```
http://www.google.com
```

**Case2**:

```
bhjhrwww.rrwww.google.com
```

Result:

```
www.google.com
```

Comment: Post the regex you tried , not the blog you readed.

Comment: i couldn't do it as SO considers the regex string as URL and not allows me to post.

Comment: Did you try to enclose the regex with backticks to mark it as code as is explained in [advanced help here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Lets be realistic: bhjhrwww.rrwww.google.com is also a valid URL identifier. You're not looking to parse an url from a String - you're looking to parse an url from a String which will can actually be succesfully requested which in this example would be only 'www.google.com' or 'google.com'. You can't achieve that result with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\(?(http://(?!.*http)|www[.](?!.*www))[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]+[.][-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%=~_()|]*\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/24

Comment: seems like your regex matches `www.com` .

Comment: @AvinashRaj now it wont

Comment: Yes it also considers www.com as valid URL.

Comment: now, it matches `www..com` . It's so hard to match the link that op wants.